# Fix Too many re-renders Errors in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I wrote a crop editor image profile but I want to change a state variable if file is picked up.

```
<input 
    type="file"
    name="profilePicBtn"
    accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
    onChange={profilePicChange}
    id="upload"
    style={{display:"none"}}
/>
```

this is my input element and in continue we have

```
 let test = document.getElementById('upload')
```

and my props are

```
 <CropImage 
      imageSrc={selectedImage}
      setEditorRef={editor}
      onCrop={onCrop}
      scaleValue={scaleValue}
      onScaleChange={onScaleChange}
      onTest={test}
    />
```

and in other component we have

```
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

   if (onTest != null) {
      console.log('done')
      setIsModalOpen(true)
   }
```

but I got trapped in a infinite loop and receive this error

> react-dom.development.js:16317 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use React `useEffect` for this purpose. And by using `onTest` inside the dependency array of the `useEffect` it will ensure `useEffect` will be triggered in each time `onTest` value is being changed. Probably in your scenario it will be called twice (from `null` to given value).

```
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(()=> {
  if(onTest != null) {
     console.log('done')
    setIsModalOpen(true)
   }
}, [onTest])
```

Comment: It works but if I want to change a picture again it won't work and I should refresh my page and run it again . how can I fix it?

Comment: should I set 'onTest' state variable?

Comment: i set  const test = document.getElementById('upload').value but it give me this error             Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating state in every render causes another render. This is what you do with `setIsModalOpen(true)`, hence the infinite loop. The condition `if(onTest != null)` is probably always true.